# Building a custom car

Tags: transmission, mercedes-benz

I'm curious, is it possible (and how hard would it be) to build a custom car with an engine from a different brand than the transmission?

For example, I'd get an old V12 Mercedes engine (with two turbo chargers), and add a DSG gearbox to it. I guess it's not really that 'plug-in-and-work' type of conversion.

(As you can tell I have little to no experience on this yet, but I am very keen on trying to build a custom vehicle).

Thanks!

Comment: Is it carbureted or fuel injected?  That going to make a **huge** difference in the difficulty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the bell housings are removable, you can swap them.  You may need to drill/weld a bit to get holes to line up.  If they are not removable you will need to either make an adaptor plate, or cut/weld the bell housing to fit.